# Why does the progress bar stop at 27% when I try to run my application?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I'm using Eclipse Indigo to develop Android. It often happens that when I click on Run, the emulator does not start. The progress bar stops at 27%.
I am forced to restart Eclipse. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you get any output in the "Problems" and "Console" in Eclipse? It might point out the error for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have build automatically set in the project menu, and that before you press the green run button, click the arrow next to it and set up the applications run configurations.

Part of these run configs are whether you manually select an emulator, or get it to run automatically with a specified one. The emulators must be created in the AVD manager sometime before they can be run.

Hope this solves your problem